# How to make style.css works well in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I try to make this style.css loading works:

site/views/header.php

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-inline-css'  href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/slider/settings-inline.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--style css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='yith-wcwl-main-css'  href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

site/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/masterlinkci2/';
```

---

I test this in the url:   `http://localhost/masterlinkci2/assets1/css/style.css`

I wonder why: Object not found!

I have that file in: `masterlinkci2/assets1/css/style.css`

This does not works out either:

```
<!--style css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='yith-wcwl-main-css'  href="<?php echo base_url('assets1/css/style.css'); ?>" type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Do I need to configure the router as well?

Comment: Have you remove index and Change the .htaccess file ?

Comment: Have you tried this URL?
 http://localhost/masterlinkci2/index.php/assets1/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

First of all load `url` helper like this.You can load helper either in controller or in `application/config/autoload.php`.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then try like this...

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='yith-wcwl-main-css'  href="<?php echo base_url('assets1/css/style.css');?>" type='text/css' media='all' />
```

For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: I already have: site/config/autoload.php  --->   $autoload['helper'] = array('url');   and still unable to load the style.css correctly.

Comment: did you use `.htaccess` for removing `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I probably think you have not setup your url rewrite with .htaccess. I would recommend you setup URL rewrite and try with:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url("assets1/css/style.css") ?>' />
```

Or if are not planning to use URL rewrite then add index.php in your path. Like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url("index.php/assets1/css/style.css") ?>' />
```

Check [this](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750) for URL rewrite

Comment: I place the .htaccess in application/site/.htaccess  and use this for style <link rel='stylesheet' id='yith-wcwl-main-css'  href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />   and still the style does not seems to load correctly.

Comment: You would need to place your .htaccess in the root of your project. Not inside application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your Base Url :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Your CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Hope this works.

remove index from congif:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And Change the .htaccess file as give below. add this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works fine for me.

I don't sure about removing index is the best practice but it makes lot's of work easier. so I have done that. do what your mind say.

Answer (score 0):

Try your stylesheet link like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets1/css/style.css');?>" media="screen">
```

Your URL needs to be inside the ()